# Not too old of a question, with answers, was deleted, why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I answered a question like a month back concerning the radius of convergence of a specific series where the poster had a polynomial so I pointed out that convergence is all of $\mathbb{R}$, not the most interesting question but since nothing was done until today I am confused by its deletion. My answer to that question was accepted and up voted a couple of times which means the poster themselves can not have deleted it according to [the help center post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).

I cannot see the reasons for deletion so could someone please explain why it was deleted now?

Comment: I'm going to upvote your post, for the record this post of Meta was downvoted a minute ago after you've edited.

Comment: Without including a link to the question that was asked, I'm afraid we can't help you too much.  When a question is very low quality, it might be closed, and when a question is closed, so are all the answers to it.  If you have a link, perhaps we can then see whether your answer alone was deleted, or the entire post.

Comment: @amWhy I sadly do not have a link. My reputation is to low to see deleted content I suppose.

Comment: For those who can see deleted posts: please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767233/what-is-the-radius-of-convergence-of-a-n-where-a-n1-fracn-5n1a-n).  @AndréArmatowski  It was the question that was closed for lacking context of any sort, then deleted.  As I said, when a question is closed, then deleted, any answers to it are also deleted.  The question you answered was a very poor post not meeting site standards.  In the future, please be more careful when selecting posts you choose to answer.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for the clarification, that answers my question. I am not disagreeing with its deletion, but I am disagreeing with not being notified.

Comment: I think you should be able to see your answer listed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/649348. That is the link to "Recently Deleted Answers", available at the bottom of the "Answers" tab on your profile.